# Solidity unit testing isn't using the correct sender to call the function under test

Tags: unit-testing, testing, ethereum, solidity, remix

```
pragma solidity 0.6.12;

// This import is automatically injected by Remix
import "remix_tests.sol"; 

import "remix_accounts.sol";
import "./LottoMock.sol";

... other test cases

contract lottoMultipleEntranceTest {

LottoMock lotto;

/// #sender: account-0
/// #value: 500000000000000
function beforeEach() public payable {
    lotto = new LottoMock();
    
    Assert.equal(lotto.getQuantityOfEntrants(), uint256(0), "expecting 0 entrants before entering");
    Assert.equal(lotto.getLotteryBalance(), uint256(0), "expecting 0 lottery balance before entering");
    Assert.equal(msg.sender, TestsAccounts.getAccount(0), "Invalid sender");

    
    lotto.enter{value:500000000000000}();
    
    Assert.equal(lotto.getLotteryBalance(), uint256(500000000000000), "expecting lottery balance equal to entrance fee after entering");
    Assert.equal(lotto.getQuantityOfEntrants(), uint256(1), "user should have successfully entered the lottery");
}

//TODO: needs debugging
///case 7: multiple entrants
/// #sender: account-1
/// #value: 500000000000000
function enterSuccessfullyMultipleEntrants() public payable {
    Assert.equal(lotto.getLotteryBalance(), uint256(500000000000000), "One user has already entered.");
    Assert.equal(lotto.getQuantityOfEntrants(), uint256(1), "Expecting an existing entry.");
    Assert.equal(msg.sender, TestsAccounts.getAccount(1), "Invalid sender");

    //TODO - this is using account-0
    try lotto.enterDebug1{value:500000000000000}() {
        Assert.ok(false, 'succeed unexpected');
    } catch Error(string memory reason) {
        Assert.equal(reason, "debug", "debug.");
    } catch (bytes memory /*lowLevelData*/) {
        Assert.ok(false, 'failed unexpected');
    }
    
    Assert.equal(lotto.getLotteryBalance(), uint256(1000000000000000), "expecting lottery balance equal to entrance fee for two users after entering");
    Assert.equal(lotto.getQuantityOfEntrants(), uint256(2), "second user should have successfully entered the lottery");
}
}
```

The issue that I am having is in the `enterSuccessfullyMultipleEntrants` test, even though     `Assert.equal(msg.sender, TestsAccounts.getAccount(1), "Invalid sender");` is working correctly, the `lotto.enterDebug1{value:500000000000000}()` line is still being called with test account 0, not account-1. Can someone please advise on what I'm doing wrong here?

Reference: https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/unittesting.html#customization

Comment: Opened a bug report: https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project/issues/1618

Answer (score 0):

When you say `try lotto.enterDebug1{}` we are marking an external call. In that case, `msg.sender` is set to the calling contract's address (i.e., `address(this)`, not to `account-0`.
Even if you set `#sender: account-0` this seems to not work. You can observer this by returning `msg.sender` from called contract and comparing that with `address(this)`.

For example, assume following in our called contract:

```
contract Called{
...

    funtion sender() public returns(address){
        return msg.sender;
    }
}
```

Then in our calling contract:

```
Called c = new Called();

/// #sender: account-0
function test() public{
    try c.sender() returns (address a){
        Assert.equal(a, address(this), 'Should be same');
    }
```